# OpenCart head into body

Tags: html, opencart, head

I have  web with cms Open Cart, and i have  problem with my order page, the tag head in this page appear into body tag, how you can see in this code, but this only appear in chrome, I see it well in firefox or IE.

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="es" class="wf-loading wf-opensans-n6-loading">
<head></head>
<body style="position: static;">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
            <base href="http://tcgfactory.com/">
                <link href="http://tcgfactory.com/image/data/cart.png" rel="icon">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                        href="catalog/view/theme/fortis/stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                            href="catalog/view/theme/fortis/stylesheet/responsive.css">
                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                                href="catalog/view/theme/fortis/stylesheet/menu-default.css"
                                id="menu_rel"
```

In other page in my web content of head appear in tag , as you can see here.

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="es" class="wf-opensans-n6-active wf-active">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Mi Cuenta</title>
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
            <base href="http://tcgfactory.com/">
                <link href="http://tcgfactory.com/image/data/cart.png" rel="icon">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                        href="catalog/view/theme/fortis/stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                            href="catalog/view/theme/fortis/stylesheet/responsive.css">
                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                                href="catalog/view/theme/fortis/stylesheet/menu-default.css"
                                id="menu_rel">
                                <script
                                    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"
                                    type="text/javascript" async=""></script>
                                <script type="text/javascript"
                                    src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
                                <script type="text/javascript"
                                    src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
                                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                                    href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">
                                    <script type="text/javascript"
                                        src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/external/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
                                    <script type="text/javascript"
                                        src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
                                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                                        href="catalog/view/theme/fortis/stylesheet/custom_colorbox.css"
                                        media="screen">
                                        <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/tabs.js"></script>
```

Add image with the problem, where we can see the "red dot".

[image]

I try many things, but I don't get  solution for this problem.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Have You installed some extension? Looks like the HTML is manipulated by some extension - probably via vQmod.

Comment: yes I changed somes files like order_info.tpl, header.tpl and some more. And the problem only appear in chrome, in firefox and IE appear correctly.